# Permutations of seven numbers such that none of the sums are divisible by 3

Tags: elementary-number-theory, permutations

How many permutations $(a_1,\dots, a_7)$ of $(2,3,4,5,6,7,8)$ exist such that none of the sums

$a_1$,

$a_1+a_2$,

...

$a_1+a_2+\dots a_7$

are divisible by $3$?

I tried to study the cases of the possible $3$-remainders for members of such permutations, but I found that there are just too many possibilities. I hope there is some simple idea that I just can't see.

Comment: Interesting question:  Try to figure out how to arrange (-1, 0,1,-1,0,1,-1,0) so that none of the sums are 0, 3, or -3 first.  Then figure out how many ways there are to replace -1 with 2,5 or 8.  1 with 4 or 7 and 0 with 3,6,9.

Comment: not addition is commutative.

Comment: Hmm... not sure I read that as including 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Studying remainders has to be the place to start. So we have $2$ numbers divisible by three (=remainder $0$), $2$ numbers with remainder $1$ and $3$ numbers with remainder $2$.

The remainder-$0$ numbers can be inserted at any point within or after a sequence of the other numbers that otherwise qualifies; they will not there "break" a qualifying sequence and will not "fix" a non-qualifying sequence.

So we can focus on the other $5$ numbers first:

- If we start with a rem $1$ number, another $1$ must follow but then we have only rem $2$ numbers left, and we cannot avoid a running total divisible by $3$.
- If we start with a rem-$2$ number, another $2$ must follow, then $1$ and $2$ to avoid $6$, finally $1$.

So only a remainder sequence matching  $22121$ is suitable.  We have $3!=6$ options for placing the remainder-$2$ numbers, $2!=2$ for the rem-$1$s. Then we can insert the rem-$0$ numbers in $\binom 62 = 15$ patterns and $2$ orders.

So we have $3!\cdot 2! \cdot \binom 62 \cdot 2 =360$ options.

Answer (score 2):

We can't start with a number that is congruent $0 \mod 3$.  so we must start with one that is congruent $\pm 1 \mod 3$.  If we start $1 \mod 3$ we can't have a $-1 \mod 0$ before we have the second $1\mod 3$.  If we start with a $1 \mod 3$ then have some zeros modulo three, another $1 \mod 3$ we will have no more $1\mod 3$s, so we will have to have, at some point, two $-1 \mod 3$s which will add to $0$.

So the first number must be congruent $-1 \mod 3$, then we must have another $-1 \mod 3$ before we have a $1 \mod 3$.  After the two $-1 \mod 3$s we can't have a third $-1\mod 3$ until we have a $1 \mod 3$.  Once we have two $-1 \mod 3$s and one $1\mod 3$ we must have the third $-1 \mod 3$ before the second $1\mod 3$.

So the order must be $-1\mod 3, *, -1\mod 3, *, 1 \mod 3, *, -1\mod 3, *, 1 \mod 3, * $, where $*$ are zero or more $0\mod 3$.  So of the six remaining places, the two $0\mod 3$ can go anywhere.

So there are ${6 \choose 2}$ ways to arrange $(-1\mod 3,0\mod 3,1\mod 3,-1\mod 3,0\mod 3,1\mod 3,-1\mod 3,0\mod 3)$.

$2,5,8 \equiv -1 \mod 3$ and there are $3!$ ways to order those.  $2!$ ways to order $4,7 \equiv 1 \mod 3$ and $2!$ ways to order $3,6\equiv 0 \mod 3$.

So there are ${6 \choose 2}3!*2!*2! = \frac {6!}{4!2!}*6*2*2 = \frac{5*6}26*2*2 =5*6*6*2 =360$ ways to do this.

Comment: Argh!  DOn't know why I was so dyslexically insisting that $9$ was in the original set, when it obviously wasn't.

Comment: I guess if you included 9 in the set I would get $3!2!\binom 73 3!=2520$ which I think you had at one point in the edit process :-)

Comment: Exactly.  Then I realized the 9 wasn't in it, and I slowly corrected corecting one of the terms but not the rest, and then another but not the rest...First the ${7 \choose 3}$ to ${7 \choose 2}$ but keeping the $7$ and the $3!$.  Then the 3! with the 2!but but keeping the 7.  Then replacing the 7  with 6  but keeping the $5!$ in the denominator.... sheesh.

Comment: Thank both of you for the nice solutions! I just complicated the solution because I distinguished all cases of placing the remainder-0 numbers.

Comment: It was not an easy nor intuitive problem.  Trying them number by number would have been far too many.  The trick is to do it by remainders... and even then it isn't obvious.  If the numbers had gone up to 11, it would have been very hard.  As you could have -1,-1, 1,-1,-1 as well as -1,-1,1,-1,1.